# HTTP Error 0 js/upload in drupal when attaching a file

Tags: drupal

I am trying to attach an 8M .wav file to a "story" in drupal. I can attach similar smaller files, but when i try this one and larger sizes i get in HTTP Error 0 message after a minute or to. I have checked all my max upload, Max Mem sizes they are set at well over 8M at 64M and 256M. Anyone else have this issue uploading files ever?

Comment: are you uploading the file via the ajax submission button, or by previewing or saving the node?

Comment: I am suffering it while uploading file via AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the script timeout is reached before the file is uploaded, try to set a higher maximum execution time for your php scripts.

The file size limits in php are upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, you can also try to increase those, see also http://drupal.org/node/97193

Comment: Timeout has been set to 3 minutes, upload is failing after 2 or so, I can try to set it higher

Comment: @user349294 There are also quite a few different options that limit the maximum file size. Those could also be the problem, although mostly they should fail before trying to upload. The first is in php.ini, then there is at least one in default Drupal and if you're using Filefield there are even more filesize limits.

Comment: The php execution time doesn't start until the file is fully uploaded; you could spend an hour uploading a 2GiB file, and a max_execution_time value of 30 seconds wouldn't be a problem.  The input time is a possibility, but php *shouldn't* spend very much time parsing the request data.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a lot of possible reasons for this error, and the main problem is that Drupal core does not report any detail on AJAX failures - thus anything could be going wrong, but you're just seeing the "Error 0" text.

One possible way to diagnose this is to turn JavaScript off (for example, by using NoScript in FireFox) and try uploading again - then you may see the full error text, which will tip you in the direction of further investigation.

Some more discussion and some possible solutions (you'll see that there are many, since there are many possible causes to this problem) can be found here: http://drupal.org/node/297035?mode=2&sort=2

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your tip to disable JavaScript was extremely useful. When I did that, I found out that the problem was not Drupal in my case but the reverse proxy nginx: `413 Request Entity Too Large   (nginx/0.7.67)`. When I set the nginx directive `client_max_body_size 30M;` the problem was gone ;)

Answer (score 2):

I installed the jquery update module and its fixed.

Install the jquery update from:
http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Comment: When you install the jQuery module it sets the default version of jQuery to 1.5 and I was still getting the error.  I changed it to version 1.8 using admin/config/development/jquery_update and the error went away.